# image not uploading/moving into folder

Tags: php, html, mysqli

i am uploading an image , image title is getting added to database but the file(image is not uploading/moving to the folder), i am getting 404 error for that image , i have set that folder permissions to 0777 and also max upload is 1024MB

```
$article_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname('_FILE_')));
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,SITE_ROOT.'/images/$article_image');
$add="insert into articles(article_title,article_date,article_author,category,article_image,article_keywords,article_content) values ('$article_title','$article_date','$article_author','$article_category','$article_image','$article_keywords','$article_content')" ;
if(mysqli_query($conn,$add)== 1 ){
echo "<script> alert('article added')</script>";
}
else{
echo "failed".mysqli_error($conn) ;
}
}
```

what mistake am i doing ?

EDIT here is my html code

```
<form method="post" action="addarticle.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<table align="center">
      <tr>
                   <td align="center"><h1> ADD ARTICLE</h1></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td>Article Title</td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
              <tr>

                   <td>Article Keyword</td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="keywords"></td>
              <tr>
                   <td>Article Image</td>
                       <td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
              </tr>
                           <td>Article Content</td>
                       <td><textarea name="content" cols="90" rows="30"></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
              </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,SITE_ROOT."/images/$article_image");` use double quotes. Variables do not get parsed in single quotes, unless concatenated. Plus, use 755 for folders, not 777.

Comment: done but still not working

Comment: and if i use 0755 i am getting permission denied error

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file larger than 1024? Plus, on localhost or hosted?

Comment: nope just a 600 kb file

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: yep i've already added it (thats why i can see permission denied error) ... the worst thing is that same code worked perfectly in my localhost

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and base yourself on example #1. This, while removing the `define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname('_FILE_')));` and related constant, and using a standard upload method, as defined in the link I gave you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your line with:

```
realpath(dirname('__FILE__'));

__FILE__
```

is a magic constant, and should not be wrapped in single or double quotes.

If you were to echo out the result of that function call you would probably see a different path than what you're expecting.

You're also trying to use string interpolation with single quotes around the variable instead of double:

```
SITE_ROOT.'/images/$article_image';
```

Should be:

```
SITE_ROOT."/images/$article_image";
```

Example:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image'])) {
  $tmp_file_to_upload = $_FILES['image'];
  if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     $uploaded_name = $tmp_file_to_upload['name'];
     $tmp_name = $tmp_file_to_upload['tmp_name'];
     $destination = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."images/$uploaded_name";
     if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destination)) {
        die('Error uploading file.');
     }
  } else {
    die('Error uploading file.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Variable concatenation issue `'/images/'.$article_image`

```
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,SITE_ROOT.'/images/'.$article_image);
```

instead of

```
 move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,SITE_ROOT.'/images/$article_image');
```